# Calculate rank of values in array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array i.e.

```
Array
(
    [18] => 0.6667
    [228] => 0.3333
    [25] => 0.3333
    [568] => 0.3333
    [762] => 0
    [740] => 0
    [742] => 0
)
```

I want to rank them as

```
Array
(
    [18] => 0.6667  //1
    [228] => 0.3333 //2
    [25] => 0.3333  //2
    [568] => 0.3333  //2
    [762] => 0       //3
    [740] => 0       //3
    [742] => 0       //3
)
```

I have tried using following code:

```
arsort($rank);
foreach ($rank as $k => $v) {
        $i=1;
        foreach ($rank as $k1 => $v1) {
            if($v==$v1){
                $newrank[$k]=$i;
            }
            else{
                $i++;  
            }     
        }
    }
```

But it gives me result

```
Array
(
    [18] => 0.6667  //1
    [228] => 0.3333 //2
    [25] => 0.3333  //2
    [568] => 0.3333  //2
    [762] => 0       //5
    [740] => 0       //5
    [742] => 0       //5
)
```

I am unable to rectify why rank is increasing from 2 to 5.

Please help.

Comment: What is the logic in that "rank"?

Comment: @AlmaDo same values at same rank. as given in second array

Comment: How then it differs from ordinary sort?

Comment: @Rikesh He's storing it in `$newrank`.

Comment: @Rikesh calculating on the fly. Not saving anywhere

Comment: @AlmaDo when value is same for two users then rank should remain same. that is the problem

Comment: @Rikesh Ranks are repeated for same value

Comment: sort, then traverse. couldn't be easier.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but where I am wrong I am traversing it using my code. But it gives much difference in two different ranks. After two there is no 3 but 5

Comment: @Rikesh Ranks are sequential numbers 1, 2, 3, ... for first place, second place, and so on.

Comment: there's no need for a *double* loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need nested loops. Just iterate through the array, and increment `$i` whenever the score changes.

```
$newrank = array();
$i = 0;
$last_v = null;
foreach ($rank as $k => $v) {
    if ($v != $last_v) {
        $i++;
        $last_v = $v;
    }
    $newrank[$k] = $i;
}
```

Comment: I'd ask both of you: asker, answerer. what if     Array
    (
        [18] => 0.6667
        [228] => 0.3333
        [25] => 0.3333
        [568] => 0.3333
        [762] => 0
        [740] => 0.3333
        [742] => 0.6667
    )

Comment: @GeorgePHP I am already sorting it before posting to foreach using arsort()

Comment: @GeorgePHP  also updated my question with arsort() to avoid confusion.

Comment: The nested loop in the question assumed that the array was sorted (there were no greater-than comparisons between `$v` and `$v1`), so I felt free to include that assumption in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's Done..

```
foreach ($rank as $k => $v) {
        $i=1;
        foreach (array_unique($rank) as $k1 => $v1) {
            if($v==$v1){
                $newrank[$k]=$i;

            }
            else{

                $i++;  
            }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: It also works. But Barmar's answer is much efficient. Thanks.